# unable to use 'swagger.net' in visual studio 2015 while creating .net web api, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, asp.net-apicontroller

Unable to use 'swagger.net' in visual studio 2015 while creating .NET web api. Why?
I encountered an error while creating a web api based on .NET. I've installed swagger and related packages.

Error on: **SwaggerActionFilter(), XmlCommentDocumentationProvider**

My function is :

```
public static void PostStart() 
{
    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

    config.Filters.Add(new SwaggerActionFilter());

    try
    {
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IDocumentationProvider),
            new XmlCommentDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/DigiCob.XML")));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        throw new Exception("Please enable \"XML documentation file\" in project properties with default (bin\\DigiCob.XML) value or edit value in App_Start\\SwaggerNet.cs");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: who edited my post before monitoring???...

Comment: Your post was edited to cut out your swearing, because it's pointless. Nevertheless, did you add the reference to the DLL at Visual Studio's Project References?

Comment: Pretty fine... Ok bro... Could you please guide me to do so...

Comment: In your Visual Studio Project there should be an item `References`. Right-click it and go to `Add Reference...`. Then, in the window that pops up, go to the tab `Browse` and navigate to the DLL that you want to add, then click on the checkbox next to it to add it to your references.

Comment: I'm a new born baby in .net, so could you point me which DLL, my intention was just to document ma API with Swagger, i did it the same few times before, but then this error.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a file `swagger.dll` or something like that?

Comment: Couldn't resolve Ian, I think its not exactly what the problem need...

Answer (score 1):

The .NET implementation of the Swagger specification is called Swashbuckle.

Install the [Swashbuckle nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle) package and you should be fine.

Comment: I've done this bro, don't know what to install next, i think the only way to get out of this is by recreating the whole project.

Comment: Did you added the proper using statements ?

Comment: Yes bro, I'm pretty sure on that, error is to avoid unnecessary using statements, i couldn't use 'using Swagger.net '.

Comment: There's no such namespace "Swagger.net" in the Swashbuckle package. Are you using different nuget package ?

Comment: Ok, I think that you're using this implementation of swagger - https://github.com/giacomelli/DG-Swagger.Net/tree/master/Swagger.Net. You should start using https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Comment: Thanks ma friends...\